# sum() or group() virtual attributes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, virtual-attribute

let's say I have a model like this:

```
class Surface < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :width, :length

  def area
     self.width * self.length
  end
end
```

Where `@surface.area` returns the area of a surface. Now, lets say I have many surfaces called `@surfaces` and I want to sum all areas. How do I do this?

My favorite solution would look like this:

```
@surfaces.sum(:area)
```

But it does not work. So how can I call `.sum()` or `.group()` or any similar functions on a virtual attributes like this in rails? I would like to avoid `.each do |surface|` calls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum` will quite happily accept an SQL expression instead of just a column name so all you need to do is translate your `sum` method into SQL:

```
@surfaces.sum('width * height')
@surfaces.sum('surface.width * surface.height') # If you think other tables might be involved.
```

Also, class methods on your models are mixed into relations (since scopes and class methods are really the same thing) so you could add a class method to go with your instance method:

```
class Surface < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.area
    sum('surface.width * surface.height')
  end
  def area
     self.width * self.length
  end
end
```

and say:

```
@surfaces.area
```

You're usually better off letting the database do the heavy lifting with your data, that's what they're for and what they're good at.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your solution is great but I'm still corious if there is any way to make the virtual `:area` attribute as useable as the real `:width` or `:length` attributes. So I can do `.sum(:area)` or `.group(:area)` just as I would do it with `:width`. `width * height` was just a simple examlpe it should represent any calculation or even more complex function for general purpose.

Comment: Sorry but ActiveRecord isn't smart enough to translate arbitrary Ruby code to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by `Enumerable#reduce` method:

```
@surfaces.reduce(0){ |sum, surface| sum + surface.area }
```